# The ol' Regex frustration

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex and have tried to do a good bit of reading but ultimately it is not working. I am trying to match a string that is 2 letters then 4 numbers. no spaces. capital letters only. I am using

```
"^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$"
```

and when I feed it `AB1234` it say FALSE.

Where have I gone wrong and how do I make this regex work. Thanks!

**Edit:**
I have userControl (`ctrlSamplerSet`) with a textbox called `txtSamplerBarcode`.
I'm calling the usercontrol's Validate() method on the `txtSamplerBarcode.TextChanged` event which runs this method

```
private void ctrlSamplerSet_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string bc = txtSamplerBarcode.Text;
        if (bc.Contains("UP")) { _validEntry= checkForregularBarcodeSyntax(bc); }
    }
```

I pass the text property of that to my `checkForregularBarcodeSyntax` method.

```
private bool checkForregularBarcodeSyntax(string bc)
    {
        Regex regBCsyntax = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$",RegexOptions.None);
        bool matchSuccess= regBCsyntax.IsMatch(bc);
        return matchSuccess;
    }
```

matchSuccess is false in all circumstances.

I don't know if that is 'runable' enough for you?

Comment: Looks good to me. What says FALSE exactly?

Comment: That pattern is correct for the test string. Look elsewhere for your problem. Do you have any leading or trailing spaces in your string?

Comment: could you please post some runnable code?

Comment: Actually write us a small program that demonstrates the problem, and post that.

Comment: Is `AB1234` the entire string or is there anything else in it? Also, could you show the code you using to get the false?

Comment: See my edit in the question. @MichaelPetrotta I pass it strings with spaces sometimes because it is in attached to a textbox I can try a lot of different things quickly and all give the same result.

Comment: What is the value of `bc` in `checkForregularBarcodeSyntax` when the latter returns false? Use the debugger to check that, or print it to a logfile.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta oh you so wise. I was not attaching `bc` correctly. It was being passed the wrong string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is correct.  Maybe you can follow this example to discover your mistake.

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$");
Console.WriteLine (r.Match("AB1234").Success);
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried matching it without the leading `^` and trailing `$` characters, as in `[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}`?

Something like:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("AB1234", @"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}");
if (match.Success) 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is case sensitive, unless you explicitly tell it not to be, perhaps that is the cause of your issue.

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}$");
```

or

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Visual Studios Ctrl+F use regex as a testing engine (I easiest way to mass repeat your test in my opinion!)

When I ran your original query it didn't work on your sample text.

The final regex I came up with to get it to match was

```
[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]+{4}
```

I'm not sure why the [0-9]{4} wasn't working but it Regex is engine dependent.

Comment: so you type exactly that into the Find field and press find next? and it matches based on the regex?

Comment: In visual studio you have to expand find options, there is a switch for "Use Regex" and yea exactly, runs a lot faster then compiling anything. This also works in pretty much any IDE, including Microsoft office suite and most notepad editors.

Comment: Note that the the VS regexs aren't the same syntax as the C# regexs. Similar, but not exactly the same.